# How to perform ILIKE query against JSONB type column?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have column "category_products" with datatype as JSONB. In that column data is inserted as array and this array contains objects. and that object contains array of object.

Here I need to perform ILIKE query against product_name.

example

```
category_products
-----------------
[{"products":[{product_name: product_one, price: 123}, {product_name: product_two, price: 999}]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first flatten your data using a lateral join with `jsonb_path_query` and then apply an `ILIKE` in a `WHERE` clause as you need. Here is an illustration.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6YoVaH4yEE6ZcjbWZiLdTf/1).

```sql
select id, l, l ->> 'product_name' as prod
from the_table,
lateral jsonb_path_query(category_products, '$[*].products[*]') as l;
```

Please note that your sample data are not valid JSON at all.
Unrelated but this would be so much easier and cleaner with a normalized data design.

**Edit**

As `jsonb_path_query`  does not exist in pre-PG12 versions here is an alternative and a new [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6YoVaH4yEE6ZcjbWZiLdTf/2).

```sql
select id, l, l ->> 'product_name' as prod
from the_table,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(category_products) as arr_ex,
lateral jsonb_array_elements(arr_ex -> 'products') as l;
```

Comment: This SQL query is working in PostgreSQL version 12, But it is not working in version 10, So please give any other queries to work in version 10.